# socket Merchant problem, how can I solve it just sorting the array and counting the number of pairs flooring the numbers?

Tags: javascript

The problem I have to solve is this:

> There is a large pile of socks that must be paired by color. Given an
> array of integers representing the color of each sock, determine how
> many pairs of socks with matching colors there are.
>
> Example
>
> There is one pair of color and one of color . There are three odd
> socks left, one of each color. The number of pairs is
>
> .
>
> Function Description
>
> Complete the sockMerchant function in the editor below.
>
> sockMerchant has the following parameter(s):
>
> ```
> int n: the number of socks in the pile
> int ar[n]: the colors of each sock
> ```
>
> Returns
>
> ```
> int: the number of pairs
> ```

My solution in javascript since I know very little of the language was this

```
function sockMerchant(n, ar) {
    // Write your code here
    let pairs=0;
    let counter;
    ar.sort()

    for(let i=0; i < n; i++){
        if (i == 0){
            counter = 1;
        }else{
            if(ar[i] == ar[i-1]){
                counter++;
            }else{
                
                pairs= pairs + Math.floor(counter/2);
                counter= 1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return pairs
}
```

The problem is that hackerranks complains because with this input

```
10
1 1 3 1 2 1 3 3 3 3
```

my output is 2 instead of 4. Can somebody tell me why because I can't see where the problem is.
If someone can help me to see where is the issue, I will appreciate it
Thanks in advance
Jenifer

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I couldn't understand the logic of your proposed algorithm, But as an alternative solution, you may have a look at my code.
Here is my javascript code for this problem which works fine.

First, I defined a dictionary (ar_count) and count each number from ar array and update the dictionary for the corresponding key. I defined the key in the form of "key"+ar[i] for easy coding and fast processing of finding the existing key and for counting pairs.

```
function sockMerchant(n, ar) {
    var ar_count={};
    for(let i=0; i<ar.length;i++){
        if("key"+ar[i] in ar_count){
            ar_count["key"+ar[i]]+=1;
        }
        else{
            ar_count["key"+ar[i]]=1;
        }
    }
    //console.log(ar_count);
    var pairs=0;
    for (var key in ar_count){
        paires+=~~(ar_count[key]/2);
    }
    
    return pairs;
}
```